# User agent, how to have different css files for different devices automatically

Tags: javascript, php, android, css, ipad

I have a lot of problems, trying to solve some. I have a web page, but I want to redirect only the link to the css file filtering by user agent.

```
`<script type="text/css" src="style.css">
 </script>`
```

so here where is "style.css" a vant to have "style-1.css", "style-2.css", "style-2.css", "stlye-4.css"....

i found something like this:

```
<?php if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone")) || 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod")) || 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad")) || 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android")) || 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry")) || 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS"))) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin_touch.js">
<?php } else { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin_mouse.js">
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

I think this will work, but, I get mad about this devices have different resolutions, and retina display grrr.

This my css have a menu container `width:1000px`, the middle `width:600px`, and the small one 
`width:300px;`

style-1.css will be for large display over `1000px` (pc)

style-2.css will be for android tablets display over `600px` to `999px`

style-3.css will be for android and others phones display over `300px` to `599px`

style-4.css will be for iPad (1st generation & `2:1024×768 px` (132 PPI), 9.7 in )
                              3rd & 4th generation, & Air: 2048×1536 px (264 PPI), 9.7 in

style-5.css will be for iPhone 1,2,3 `320x480`; iPhone4 `640x960`, iPhone5 `640x1136`

Comment: Google "CSS media queries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://code-tricks.com/css-media-queries-for-common-devices/) has some examples for styling on common devices using *CSS media queries*

**Edit:** A small tip on how to [emulate devices for testing in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) (This has saved me tones of time on styling for multiple devices)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $check = 0;
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android") && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mobile")) 
    {
        $check = 1;
        require ("./index-mobile.html");
    }
    if (strpos ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone") || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod"))
        {
        $check = 1;
        require ("./index-mobile.html");
        }
    if (strpos ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad"))
        {
        $check = 1;
        require ("./index-ipad.html");
    }
    if (strpos ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android"))
    {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mobile"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
        $check = 1;
        require ("./index-tablet.html");
        }
    }
    if ($check == 0)
    {
        require ("./index-pc.html");
    } ?>
```

I'm happy with this!
(forgot the windows phone)
 it can be putted  :require ("some.html");

or a sting

< script type="text/javascript" src="skin_mouse.js">